# D3 Scatter or bar chart Axis Scroll

Tags: jquery, d3.js, charts

**I want to made a bar scatter chart and based on data the scroll will come on axis-**

[image]

**I made chart easily but scroll is coming on overflow of the div that contains the chart.
and not on the axis ---**

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you want some [panning and zooming](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3892928).

Comment: @Mark, No I am not looking for zooming, I just want Scroll on axis based of data..